# Is there a way to offset an arc from d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a ring, this ring using d3.js but i am having an issue i want when the ring or arc completes a full i want to offset a  little so that it looks as it going over itself.

This is what i am trying to achieve:

[image: this is what i am trying to achieve]

... and this is what i got:

[image: this is what i got]. here is my code

```
this my js code: 

/* Define properties */
const width = 500;
const height = 500;
const margin = 40;
const circleStroke = 50;
const circleSpace = 2;
const radius = (width - margin) / 2;
const fullCircle = Math.PI * 2;

const configurations = [
    {color: 'hotpink',percentage:0.5}, 
    {color: 'limegreen',percentage:0.6}, 
    {color: 'turquoise',percentage:0.9}
                             ];
/* Add SVG inside <div id="activity"></div> */
const canvas = d3.select('#activity')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)

/* Chart configuration. */

filter = canvas.append("defs")
                .append("filter")
                .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
                .attr("height", "130%"); // Adjust this value to control the shadow spread

filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
      .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
      .attr("stdDeviation", 5); // Adjust the stdDeviation value to control the blur intensity

filter.append("feOffset")
      .attr("dx", 0)
      .attr("dy", 5)
      .attr("result", "offsetblur");

var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

feMerge.append("feMergeNode");
feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
      .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");


const rings = canvas.append('g')
.attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2}, ${height / 2})`);

/* Chart configuration. */
arcs = [];
configurations.forEach((ring,index) =>{
    var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - circleStroke * (index + 1) - circleSpace * index)
    .outerRadius(radius - circleStroke * index - circleSpace * index)
    .cornerRadius(50)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(fullCircle*ring.percentage);

    arcs.push(arc); // Store arc generators in the array

    rings.append("path")
    .attr("fill",ring.color)
    .attr("d",arc);

});

// Dynamically chaninging the the value of the rings

// Array of input elements
const inputElements = [
    document.getElementById("ring1"),
    document.getElementById("ring2"),
    document.getElementById("ring3")
];

inputElements.forEach((inputElement,index)=>{
    inputElement.addEventListener("input",()=>{
        var ringPercentage = +(inputElement.value/100);
        arcs[index].endAngle(fullCircle * ringPercentage); // Update the end angle of the first arc
        console.log(ringPercentage);
        rings.select(`path:nth-child(${index + 1})`)
        .attr("fill",configurations[index].color)
        .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
        .attr("d", arcs[index]);


      

        // console.log(arcs[index].endAngle());
        if(ringPercentage==1){
            // create and append a new path to the ring
            rings.append("path");
        }

        if(ringPercentage>1){
            // create a new arc 
            var arc_new = d3.arc()
                    .innerRadius(radius - circleStroke * (index + 1) - circleSpace * index)
                    .outerRadius(radius - circleStroke * index - circleSpace * index)
                    .cornerRadius(50)
                    .startAngle(0)
                    .endAngle(fullCircle*(ringPercentage-1));

                    // get only needed path by 1 ring => 4, 2 ring=> 5,3 ring 6

            switch (inputElement.id) {
                case "ring1":
                    rings.select(`path:nth-child(4)`)
                         .attr("fill",configurations[index].color)
                         .attr("d", arc_new)
                         .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");
                    break;
            
                case "ring2":
                    rings.select(`path:nth-child(5)`)
                    .attr("fill",configurations[index].color)
                    .attr("d", arc_new)
                    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");
                    break;

                case "ring3":
                    rings.select(`path:nth-child(6)`)
                    .attr("fill",configurations[index].color)
                    .attr("d", arc_new)
                    .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)");

                     break;
            }
            
            
        }
    
    })
})


// Define the shadow filter
// Define the filter for the shadow effect

and the my html code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ring v2</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="ring1">Ring 1:</label>
        <input type="range" id="ring1" class="ring-range" min="0" max="150" step="1" value="70" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ring2">Ring 2:</label>
        <input type="range" id="ring2" class="ring-range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="90" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="ring3">Ring 3:</label>
        <input type="range" id="ring3" class="ring-range" min="0" max="150" step="1" value="40" />
    </div>
    <div id="activity"></div>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

my idea was to create a separate arc that will go over the old one but following the same path but the start of my new arc was not merging with the previous one

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt:

(You can set `delta` smaller to make arcs more smooth...)

```js
const drawCircle = (container, fullAngle, radius, width, startRGB, endRGB) => {
 const delta = 0.01;
 const steps = fullAngle / delta;
 
 for (let step = 0; step <= steps; step++) {
    const angle = step * delta;
    const x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    const y = radius * -Math.cos(angle);
  const r = Math.floor((endRGB[0] - startRGB[0]) / steps * step) + startRGB[0];
  const g = Math.floor((endRGB[1] - startRGB[1]) / steps * step) + startRGB[1];
  const b = Math.floor((endRGB[2] - startRGB[2]) / steps * step) + startRGB[2];
  const color = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
  container.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', x)
    .attr('cy', y)
    .attr('r', width / 2)
    .attr('stroke', 'none')
    .attr('fill', color);
 }
}

drawCircle(d3.select('#first'), Math.PI * 2 / 3, 80, 30, [0, 64, 192], [255, 64, 64]);
  
drawCircle(d3.select('#second'), Math.PI * 4 / 3, 80, 30, [255, 32, 32], [32, 192, 255]);

drawCircle(d3.select('#third'), Math.PI * 2, 80, 30, [32, 192, 32], [32, 32, 255]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='600' height='200'>
  <g id='first' transform='translate(100,100)'>
  </g>
  <g id='second' transform='translate(300,100)'>
  </g>
  <g id='third' transform='translate(500,100)'>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I see the idea applied here is to keep drawing mini circles at a certain rate so it appears as 1 full circle. And the fact that the circles are drawn 1 after the other would automatically create the overlapping effect. Thank you.